# How to subscribe to clear filter event in a kendo grid for Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, user-interface, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

If user clear filter in the top of the grid column, by clicking "Clear" button, then I want UI to do some other action (clear some values in the search bar for example). How to find/subscribe to such event in the kendo UI grid for Angular?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try the `filterChange` event? Read about it [here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/filtering/manual-filtering/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your component's HTML, add an event binding to the filterChange event ([documentation](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/GridComponent/#toc-filterchange)). Then in your component's TypeScript, add the reference to the filterChange event. Finally, store a variable to keep track of the column's current filter value and check when it goes from something to nothing.

For example:

```html
<kendGrid (filterChange)="kendoGridFilterChange($event)" ...>
```

```ts
private firstOrderedOnFilterValue: Date;
kendoGridFilterChange(e: CompositeFilterDescriptor): void {
  if (e.filters) {
    const firstOrderedOnFilter = e.filters.find(filter => filter.field === 'FirstOrderedOn');
    firstOrderedOnFilterValue = firstOrderedOnFilter.value;
  } else {
    if (firstOrderedOnFilterValue) {
      // filter was cleared, do something
    }
    firstOrderedOnFilterValue = null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Also if we look into filter array this.filter.filters, then we can see that particular filter is empty.. or whole array empty means all filters are cleared. 
if (this.filter.filters.length == 0)
      console.log('filters cleared');